# Get npm list output into array in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, npm

npm ls gives output in a tree structure, is there any way to store that as an array with unique elements ?

npm ls looks like this,
[image]

Does anyone know how can we do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can print the list out in json format and parse it using jq or some scripting language like so:

```
npm ls --json=true | ruby -rjson -e "x=JSON.parse(STDIN.read); puts x['dependencies'].keys"
```